# ASP.Net MVC single controller with multiple repositories

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, controller

I have a data access layer which returns repositories.
For example, I have the following repository interfaces:

I have Entity Framework implementations of these repositories. These implementations get injected at a runtime with Ninject.

I have One controller with multiple repositories given below

```
 IUploadRepository _uploadRepository;
 ISalesRepository _salesRepository; 
 ITRSalesRepository _trsalesRepository;
 ILocalPurchaseRepository _localRepository;
```

with single controller named -HomeController

In order to functional operation , I need to use DBContext into implementation thats why I implement all those interface like given below:

```
public class UploadRepository : IUploadRepository
{
    private readonly XMANEntities _entities;
    public UploadRepository(XMANEntities entities)
    {
        _entities = entities;
    }
    *here goes all implementation with context for specific*
}
```

Here now I have a constructor within a HomeController which looks this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  private IUploadRepository uploadRepository;

  public HomeController()
  {
     this.uploadRepository = new UploadRepository(new XMANContext());
  }

  public HomeController(IUploadRepository uploadRepository)
  {
     this.uploadRepository = uploadRepository;
  }
}
```

How can I use others in this controller.Is it bad practice to inject multiple repo's into a controller? 
i have tried this way like given below:

```
public HomeController() : this(new UploadRepository(
    new XMANEntities()), new SalesRepository(new XMANEntities()), 
    new TRSalesRepository(
       new XMANEntities()), new LocalPurchaseRepository(new XMANEntities()))
{
}

public HomeController(UploadRepository uploadRepository, SalesRepository salesRepository, 
      TRSalesRepository trsalesRepository, LocalPurchaseRepository localPurchaseRepository)
{
    this.uploadRepository = uploadRepository;
    this.salesRepository = salesRepository;
    this.trsalesRepository = trsalesRepository;
    this.localPurchaseRepository = localPurchaseRepository;
}
```

Comment: not at all you `can` use multiple repositories in one conntroller

Comment: You just add additional parameters - `public HomeController(IUploadRepository uploadRepository, ISalesRepository salesRepository, etc)`

Comment: thanks buti have tried but i dont know why not it instantiated. it gives exception with Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Stephen now i have edited what i have tried but it gives me Object reference not set to an instance of an object when i call function one of this repo.

Comment: You need to delete the default constructor and configure Ninject to inject the dependencies into the controller

Comment: deleted and have tried but dont know why not it instantiated. it gives exception with Object reference not set to an instance of an object. when i try to call like _uploadRepository.UploadDuplicateCheck(importeddata);

Comment: That suggests you Ninject configuration may be wrong. How have you set it up?

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly acceptable to inject multiple dependencies on an object. However, avoid it as much as possible (Except for transactional objects) to prevent mixing of responsibilities. An approach that you can look at is stored procedures.

```
 private IUploadRepository _uploadRepository;
 private ISalesRepository _salesRepository; 
 private ITRSalesRepository _trsalesRepository;
 private ILocalPurchaseRepository _localRepository;

 public HomeController(
      IUploadRepository uploadRepository,
      ISalesRepository salesRepository,
      ITRSalesRepository trsalesRepository,
      ILocalPurchaseRepository localRepository
 )
 {
     this._uploadRepository = uploadRepository;
     this._salesRepository= salesRepository;
     this._trsalesRepository= trsalesRepository;
     this._localRepository= localRepository;
 }
```

Comment: but Error CS0051 Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'ITRSalesRepository' is less accessible than method 'HomeController.HomeController(IUploadRepository, ISalesRepository, ITRSalesRepository, ILocalPurchaseRepository)'

Comment: @pythongbs Tnx for reminding man, the repository declarations should have been private

Comment: thanks error resloved but have tried but i dont know why not it instantiated. it gives exception with Object reference not set to an instance of an object. when i try to call like _uploadRepository.UploadDuplicateCheck(importeddata);

Comment: @pythongbs, this might be a different problem which could be related to the mapping of your interface and class. If this answer helped you, you can mark it as answer and post the question on another thread with more details (Source code for mapping) I'll be glad to help you with it as well ;)

Comment: @pythongbs, you're welcome man. if you find the answer helpful, upvoting it and marking it as the answer will help other people if they experience the same problem as yours.